# How to select and copy first and last rows of excel in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to select and copy the first 3 rows and the last row in an Excel worksheet but in my code below the line `Selection.Copy` gives an error.

```
Sub SaveLastLine()
    Dim WB As Workbook, filename As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Union(Range("1:3"), Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight))).Select

    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Please anyone can help me.

Comment: So it bugs on `Selection.Copy`?  What is the error message that is returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with selected ranges is probably your problem. Kellsens has given you a solution that works around this by first copying the first three rows, then copying the last row to the new worksheet.

If you want to do this all in one shot, you can first define the range, then copy the content of that range to the new workbook. Something like this:

```
Sub SaveLastLine()

    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim myRange As Range

    'copy the content
        Set myRange = Union(Range(Range("B1:B3"), Range("B1:B3").End(xlToRight)), _
                            Range(Range("B1").End(xlDown), Range("B1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)))
        myRange.Copy

    'paste the content
        Set WB = Workbooks.Add
        WB.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Karl, your codes give an error to the line of copy if any cell of first or last row is empty. How can I solve that error?.

Comment: @SchadrackRurangwa - Yes, blank cells can cause all kinds of problems in a spreadsheet.  The simplest way to fix the problem is to ensure there are no empty cells the used range. If you cannot do that, for some reason, you will need to force the ranges in your Union to be the same width before you copy them.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your new workbook, there's no activesheet to paste, that's the error cause. You could instantiate your new workbook to the declared variable Wb.
Considering that your data starts in "B1" and considering that your new worksheet will have 4 rows, I made some modifications to your code:

```
Sub SaveLastLine()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim filename As String
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' Here I instantiate the active worksheet
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add ' Here I instantiate the new workbook

    lastCol = ws.Range("B1").End(xlToRight).Column
    lastRow = ws.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row

    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 2), ws.Cells(3, lastCol)).Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Range("B1") ' Here I copy the first 3 rows and paste in the first worksheet of your new workbook
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(lastRow, 2), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Range("B4") ' Here I copy the last row and paste

    filename = "yourfilename.xlsx"
    wb.SaveAs filename

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much.